# How to acheive this animation in Blender using a Path element

Tags: animation, path

[image]I am asking for advice because I am not getting the results I was trying to get with the follow-up pass.
I want to create an animation that moves along the direction of travel like the red rectangle in the attached image. With a follow path, it bends at right angles. In fact, I want it to be like (2) and follow the slope as shown in (3).
I'm not sure if I'm explaining it well,
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, even with geometry nodes, please let me know.

Comment: So you want the rectangle to move and turn along with the path at the start and end, but not turn inbetween?

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I want to move the rectangle by rotation, then right angle, then rotation as you suggested.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Ramos San
Sorry for the lack of clarity. I will be careful in the future. Thank you very much.